# Dynamic Object Subscibe to Unique Prism Event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, prism

I am building a list based on items/objets found. When these objects are found I want them to subscribe to an event using prism/IEventAggregator. They will all be of the same type of object but I do not want them to subscribe to the same event. Even though they are of the same type I want them to have unique subscriptions. So when I publish an event I can direct it to each unique/specific object. Does anyone have any thoughts? Is this feasible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Having unique event types for each object you create would be very cumbersome and probably scale very poorly. However you can have a property on your event object that would be the specific instance you want to direct the event to.

The subscribers (your objects) would all receive the event notification but would check the 'recipient property' to see if the event is for them. If not they would ignore it, otherwise act.

Pseudo code:

```
public class MyEvent {
   public MyClass Recipient { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(IEventAggregator evt) {
      evt.Register<MyEvent>(TakeAction);
   }
   private void TakeAction(MyEvent event) {
      if (!event.Recipient == this) {
         return;
      }
      // Perform the action
   }
}
```

Comment: I started thinking along those same lines and it does make sense! I will give that a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a single event and pass a payload that contains information about the event.  Then the subscribers can filter the event based on the payload you sent with the event.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/70-CommunicatingBetweenLooselyCoupledComponents.md#subscription-filtering